# C# How to change FileAttributes from Normal to Directory

Tags: c#, file-attributes

A friend of mine gave me a corrupted SD Card which shows the "DCIM" folder as file. 
I wrote a Console program to show me FileInfo, and it returns "Normal". Now I tried to change the FileAttributes from "Normal" to "Directory" like in the sample: http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.io.file.setattributes%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var path = "O://DCIM";
        FileAttributes attributes = File.GetAttributes(path);
        attributes = RemoveAttribute(attributes, FileAttributes.Normal);
        var attr = attributes | FileAttributes.Directory;
        File.SetAttributes(path, attr);

        var fi = new FileInfo(path);
        Console.WriteLine(fi.Name + " -- " + fi.Attributes);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    private static FileAttributes RemoveAttribute(FileAttributes attributes, FileAttributes attributesToRemove)
    {
        return attributes & ~attributesToRemove;
    }
```

The program runs as expected, when I check attr before it is assigned it returns "Directory". But in the end, FileAttributes are still "Normal".

Is it possible to change FileAttributes this way?
Is there another solution to do this?

Comment: Practical part - "how to recover files from corrupted disk" is possibly ok on http://superuser.com/tour; discussion on reading/writing raw data on disk is likely too broad for SO, but there are many questions about it already. The remaining part is answered by Jim Mischell as "no".

Comment: I find it curious that `File.SetAttributes` didn't throw an exception. Looking at the reference source, it shows that `File.SetAttributes` calls `SetFileAttributes`, and throws an exception if `SetFileAttributes` returns 0. So apparently `SetFileAttributes` doesn't exit with error if you try to turn a file into a directory. Curious.

Comment: Yes, if there would have been an error I wouldn´t have asked. But everything seemed to work out fine, except that it didn´t.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the documentation for the [SetFileAttributes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365535%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) API function, which is what the call to `File.SetAttributes` resolves to:

> Files cannot be converted into directories.

If you want to get information from that device, you'll have to read raw sectors using low level device I/O. It's possible, but a lot of work.

If you're serious about getting information from that device, *do not attempt to write to it*. The data is corrupt. Attempting to modify the data on that device is more likely to further corrupt what's there. Use a low-level reader to read a binary image of what's there to a file on your hard drive. Then make a copy of that file and you can knock yourself out on the copy.

Of course, you might want to ask yourself if the data on that drive is really worth the work you're going to put into trying to recover it. Data recovery can be frustratingly tedious.